# How do I subtract milliseconds from time in this format: "2020-01-06 11:27:12.280" in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, datetime

I have time format `2020-01-06 11:27:12.280` where `.280` is milliseconds.
Want to subtract `500` milliseconds from this time and get result in same time format again.

I have tried to convert date time in epoch time using this command:

```
date +%s -d"2020-01-06 11:27:12.280
```

but is does not consider milliseconds.

Comment: Use `date`'s built-in arithmetic: `LANG=C date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%3N' --date "2020-01-06 11:27:12.280 + 0.5 sec"`

Answer (score 3):

**GNU:** Using [GNU date](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/date-invocation.html#date-invocation), it is possible to do the subtraction directly within the date-command. This is demonstrated in the [comment of Léa Gris](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59611108/how-do-i-subtract-milliseconds-from-time-in-this-format-2020-01-06-112712-28#comment105386163_59611108):

```
$ date -d "2020-01-06 11:27:12.280 - 0.5 sec" '+%F %T.%3N'
2020-01-06 11:27:11.780
```

This works here because GNU date has the possibility to query any date-string using the `-d` flag and has knowledge of nanoseconds.

**BSD/MacOS:** [BSD date](https://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/1/date/) is behaving differently. You need a bit more work here:

```
$ d="2020-01-06 11:27:12.280"
$ d=$(( $(date -j -f "%F %T" "${d%.*}" "+%s")${d#*.} - 500 ))
$ date -r "${d%${d: -3}}" "+%F %T.${d: -3}"
2020-01-06 11:27:11.780
```

**POSIX:** If you want to be POSIX compliant, it is a different story. According to the [POSIX standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/date.html), the `date` command cannot be used here as you cannot set your own date-time with the `-d` flag, and neither is there a format that specifies mili or nanoseconds. Hence, one is required to use different tools. There are many possible ways, but we will use here a version of POSIX awk:

```
awk -v d='2020-01-06 11:27:12.280' '
BEGIN{ gsub(/[-:]/," ",d); strftime_posix(mktime_posix(d)-0.5) }

# Algorithm from "Astronomical Algorithms" By J.Meeus
function mktime_posix(datestring,    a,t) {
    split(datestring,a," ")
    if (a[1] < 1970) return -1
    if (a[2] <= 2) { a[1]--; a[2]+=12 }
    t=int(a[1]/100); t=2-t+int(t/4)
    t=int(365.25*a[1]) + int(30.6001*(a[2]+1)) + a[3] + t - 719593
    return t*86400 + a[4]*3600 + a[5]*60 + a[6]
}

function strftime_posix(epoch, JD,yyyy,mm,dd,HH,MM,SS,A,B,C,D,E ) {
    if (epoch < 0 ) return "0000 00 00 00 00 00.000000"
    JD=epoch; SS=JD%60; JD-=SS; JD/=60; MM=JD%60;
    JD-=MM; JD/=60; HH=JD%24; JD-=HH; JD/=24;
    JD+=2440588
    A=int((JD - 1867216.25)/(36524.25))
    A=JD+1+A-int(A/4)
    B=A+1524; C=int((B-122.1)/365.25); D=int(365.25*C); E=int((B-D)/30.6001)
    dd=B-D-int(30.6001*E)
    mm = E < 14 ? E-1 : E - 13
    yyyy=mm>2?C-4716:C-4715
    return sprintf("%0.4d-%0.2d-%0.2d %0.2d:%0.2d:%06.3f",yyyy,mm,dd,HH,MM,SS)
}
'
```

Comment: Maybe also mention that  `-d` is a GNU `date` option and not properly portable. If you need portable code, maybe switch to a language which properly supports these constructs. A common trick is to create a simple GNU Awk, Perl, or Python script for the date calculations, and wrap it in a shell function you can use in your script.

Comment: @tripleee updated. I avoided the usage of GNU awk, Perl or Python. I sticked to pure POSIX